# In a flask application connected with an online database, are the tables created with the command 'flask run'?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Im working on flask and in application.py i have a function db.create_all() to create tables and this program has the database connection imported from models.py which defines my tables.

Now when i use only the command "flask run" tables arent created, but when i run python application.py it creates them. Shouldnt the tables be created with just the flask run command? Or this is how it is supposed to work?

EDIT: Im adding code. Application.py

```
import os
import requests

from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

from models import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db.init_app(app)

def main():
    db.create_all()

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")
```

Models.py:

```
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()


class users(db.Model): #limited size, string or varchar?
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    fname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    bday = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
```

Comment: It depends on how youve coded your application to run. Without including your code here how are people supposed to know how your application should work or how it does work. If youre learning flask I recommend miguel grinbergs flask mega tutorial. It goes through a lot of stuff and should answer most questions you have.

Comment: @Craicerjack will check him out. i added the code too

Comment: are you deploying your `Flask` app on production server ?

Comment: @cizario erm  the database is being hosted online, by 'heroku' if that is what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to setup/create database using `Flask` you have basically two options:

- set it up **manually** via `Flask shell` command

use `Shell Context` (read more [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=shell_context_processor#flask.Flask.shell_context_processor)) to load **automatically** all Model objects:

```
@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return { 'db': db, 'users': users .. }
```

now in your `shell` you can manipulate all objects:

```
(venv) $ flask shell
>>> db
<SQLAlchemy engine=mysql+pymysql://root:password@server-ip:3306/database-name> # something similar to that
>>> users
<class 'app.models.users'>
>>> db.create_all() #  the command to create database
```

- create your custom `Flask` command (read more [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#custom-commands)):

by default, `Flask` (fresh installation) provides you with 3 commands `routes`, `run` and `shell`

```
(venv) $ flask --help
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  A general utility script for Flask applications.

  Provides commands from Flask, extensions, and the application. Loads the
  application defined in the FLASK_APP environment variable, or from a
  wsgi.py file. Setting the FLASK_ENV environment variable to 'development'
  will enable debug mode.

    > set FLASK_APP=hello.py
    > set FLASK_ENV=development
    > flask run

Options:
  --version  Show the flask version
  --help     Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  routes  Show the routes for the app.
  run     Run a development server.
  shell   Run a shell in the app context.
```

now, you can create your command `db:create` (just because i really like `Symfony/Laravel`  naming convention for  console commands and i don't like nesting commands like `click` does)

```
@app.cli.command("db:create")
def db_create():
    """
    Recreate database ..
    """
    db.drop_all()  # if your want to recreate it
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()
    print('Your database is successfully created!')
```

and now

```
(venv) $ flask --help
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
[..]
Commands:
  db:create  Recreate database ..
  routes     Show the routes for the app.
  run        Run a development server.
  shell      Run a shell in the app context.
```

to create your database :

```
(venv) $ flask db:create --help
Usage: flask db:create [OPTIONS]

  Recreate database ..

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

(venv) $ flask db:create
Your database is successfully created!
```

and finally you don't need this code anymore

```
def main():
    db.create_all()
```